# Tesseract OCR Execution process for my ANDROID app

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, cygwin, tesseract

First of all, I would like to mention my requirements:

I have been working on an ANDROID Application since a couple of months. I need the code of OCR (Optical Character Recognition) in order to link that to my app through CYGWIN, JNI, NDK. I found that TESSERACT OCR is the only open source code available. I have downloaded the code of Tesseract OCR-3.00 from the following link:

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ReadMe

I successfully compiled the code in CYGWIN environment as per the steps mentioned in the "INSTALL" file present in the downloaded file. Finally all the MAKE files are generated. In order to use this code in my app, I need the ".so" file, which will be generated through CYGWIN..

Now, the problem am facing is:

I have imported the complete code Tesseract OCR into my Android app code in ECLIPSE as per the steps mentioned in the following link:

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

I had followed the procedure as mentioned in the above link..but importing the code of TESSERACT OCR is as tough as a hell when compared to the example given in the above link.
The final step where the ".so" is to be created is not working in the case of OCR..The error as shown in the following image![enter image description here][1]

SUGGESTIONS:
Plz suggest me the clear explaination on how to proceed with the next steps....plz plz..someone, plz do take some time to give clear explaination..

Thanks & Regards

Comment: show the error that you are getting

Comment: The tesseract-android-tools project (http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/) compiles fine on OSX and Ubuntu. Consider trying that.

Answer (score 0):

when I tried working with Tesseract, I was not able to get it working with Windows and Cygwin. Even I used the same references as you did. Then after I tried compiling the 'tesseract-android-tools'. And it was not working either. After that I used a MAC with the native C environment for compilation and it worked. Maybe you Google after 'tesseract-android-tools' and you'll get a lot of help.

Hope it helps a bit for further progress.

Regards